# Visual Studio, C#: Code Analysis requests a serialization constructor on a class "alias"

Tags: c#, serialization, code-analysis

I created the following equivalent of an alias:

```
public class TagAttributes : Dictionary<String, String> { }
```

Code Analysis stated I need to mark this as serializable, which I did.

```
[Serializable()]
public class TagAttributes : Dictionary<String, String> { }
```

Next, Code Analysis stated I need to include a constructor with the following signature:

```
protected TagAttributes(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

From this, I know that the following method would also have to be included:

public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)

My question is, what do I put inside these methods? There is no instance, so there's nothing to reference for the serialization. This is an "alias".

I assume I would mark them as virtual. But even then, what would I have to put inside in order to serialize the dictionary instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your class derives from `Dictionary<string, string>` and is most likely just adding a few extras, you could just call the base class constructor.
`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx4ybycc.aspx`

Answer (score 2):

If you want an alias, use this:

```
using TagAttributes = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;
```

Comment: The only problem with using is that I have to define this in each code file, which is why I opted against it. What I had was simpler... until now.

Comment: @IanC Do you have a common `using` statement in all of your files? If you do you could just use a project-wide regex find-and-replace.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... could you provide an example please?

Comment: @IanC Wait, are you using VS2012 or 2010?

Comment: Right. Turn on regex find and replace, in the find put (using System;) (with the brackets). Then in the replace put $1\nusing TagAttributes = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>; Then, change the find and replace scope to the whole solution/project. Then click replace all.